# How to check the string is getting whether is getting the Mon Sep 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

i am getting the format from server is : `Mon Sep 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Some times I am getting `05/09/2016.(dd/MM/yyyy)`

How can check whether i am getting  `Mon Sep 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` this format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your server get the date? That is, which method does it use?

Comment: Check if the string contains GMT and if it does, you know getting full version

Comment: Simply test for `"(India Standard Time)"` in the string or for the pattern: `/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/.test(dateString)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume irrespective of the format, you want to create date object and use it. For such situations, you should use `moment.js`. But if not, you can try something like this:

```js
function getDateFromString(str) {
  var date1 = null;
  if (str.trim().indexOf(" ") > -1)
    date1 = new Date(str);
  else {
    var seperator = null;

    if (str.indexOf("/") > -1)
      seperator = "/"
    else
      seperator = "-"
    str = str.split(seperator).reverse().join(seperator);
    console.log(str)
    date1 = new Date(str);
  }
  return date1;
}

var a = "Mon Sep 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
var b = "05/09/2016";

alert(getDateFromString(a));
alert(getDateFromString(b));
```

Comment: Strings should never be parsed using the Date constructor. None of the formats in the OP are required to be correctly parsed by ECMAScript implementations and they differ in how they do so.

Comment: Well there ideal approach would be to communicate to server to send only one format. Also point taken for not using string inside constructor.